# Search bar in the models.CharField containing choiches Django

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted to know if there is a way to insert a search bar in the Django choices, that is instead of manually searching the various choices if it is possible to use a filter bar to search for our choice in Django Admin - Models.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think [**`django-filter`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/) library provide you with maybe good facilities for this purpose, I have briefly given you some examples from it's documentation below:

[**`ChoiceFilter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=TypedChoiceFilter#choicefilter)

> This filter matches values in its `choices` argument. The `choices` must be explicitly passed when the filter is declared on the `FilterSet`.

```py
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name = SubCharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = SubSubCharField(max_length=100)

    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=0)

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'Regular'),
    (1, 'Manager'),
    (2, 'Admin'),
)

class F(FilterSet):
    status = ChoiceFilter(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['status']
```

---

[**`TypedChoiceFilter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=TypedChoiceFilter#typedchoicefilter)

> The same as `ChoiceFilter` with the added possibility to convert value to match against. This could be done by using coerce parameter. An example use-case is limiting boolean choices to match against so only some predefined strings could be used as input of a boolean filter:

```py
import django_filters
from distutils.util import strtobool

BOOLEAN_CHOICES = (('false', 'False'), ('true', 'True'),)

class YourFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    flag = django_filters.TypedChoiceFilter(choices=BOOLEAN_CHOICES,
                                            coerce=strtobool)
```

---

[**`MultipleChoiceFilter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=TypedChoiceFilter#multiplechoicefilter)

> The same as `ChoiceFilter` except the user can select multiple choices and the filter will form the OR of these choices by default to match items. The filter will form the AND of the selected choices when the `conjoined=True` argument is passed to this class.

> Multiple choices are represented in the query string by reusing the same key with different values (e.g. ‘’?status=Regular&status=Admin’’).

---

[**`TypedMultipleChoiceFilter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=TypedChoiceFilter#multiplechoicefilter)

> Like `MultipleChoiceFilter`, but in addition accepts the `coerce` parameter, as in `TypedChoiceFilter`.

---

See also:

- [**`django-filter`** <sup>[Docs]</sup>](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [**`django-filter`** <sup>[Github]</sup>](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter)